# Calling from JavaScript to ASP.NET View functionality with new values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` view list that I initialize with const values when page loads

```
@{
    var start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0);
    var end = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 14, 30, 0);
}


<div>
    @for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
    {
        <a class="list">
                <img src="~/Content/icon-t.png">
                @i
        </a>
    }
</div>
```

After click on `DIV` I getting data by `AJAX` and creating an JavaScript object with that data.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Data/GetData",
        success: function (data) {  
                //creating object with those values

        }
    });
```

I'm looking for a way to past my new values (`start,end`) to the code above and create the list again.

I can do it in JS by building dynamically a new list every time with the new values, but I'm looking for a way passing this responsibility to the server side by sending new values.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in JS? That would be the better solution if you ask me.

Comment: The original code is in `ASP.NET`, this is a feature I'm adding, don't want to mess to much the environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by creating a ViewModel for start/end. Then create a partial view, with the markup from the view you have. Then just make your main view a placeholder...

```
<div id="myContent">
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", new StartEndModel { Start = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0), End = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 14, 30, 0) })
</div>
```

And, upon click, or whatever, just reload the placeholder with a call to the partial view, as you pass the new data.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Data/MyPartialView",
        data: {
            start: newStart,
            end: newEnd
        },
        success: function (data) {  

            $("#MyPartialView").html(data);
        }
    });
```

(You will of course need a Controller action (Data/MyPartialView) to return the partial.)

If I am understanding your question, that is how I would start...